# Xamarin Essentials Share does not have load option

Tags: xamarin, share, xamarin.essentials

My app backs up its data in a zip file that uses Share.RequestAsync to store the file.  This works great because it presents all the possible sharing options including email, messaging, and cloud devices like Google Drive, Dropbox, etc.

In order to load that zip file from wherever it was stored I use FilePicker.PickAsync.  The problem is that this presents a very limited number of options for selecting the file.  It offers either the local device or a single cloud service (iCloud on iOS or Drive on Android).  What if I want to restore the zip file from Drive in my app on my iPhone?

Why is there such a difference in the xamarin share options when it comes to saving and loading files?  It seems like the Share class should offer a method to load files that presents the same options that it does for sharing.  Or at least the FilePicker.PickAsync should present the same interface as Share.RequestAsync for load options.  Am I missing something?

Here is what the share dialog looks like compared to the file picker on iOS.  It is similar on Android.  The share offers access to iCloud, Drive and Dropbox while the picker only offers access to iCloud.

[image: Share (save)]
[image: Pick (load)]

Comment: you seem to be expecting "Share" to behave as a "Save" option when that is not the intent.  I can share data with the Messages app, but it doesn't make sense to expect that I should also be able to load that data from Messages.  Do you know of any other apps that behave the way you expect?

Comment: Of course I don't expect to load data from the messaging apps.  However, I would like to load data from the same cloud services that I can share to.  That allows me to share from an iOS device and load the same data file with an Android device.  As it is I have to copy the file between iCloud and Drive (or Dropbox) outside my app, which is not a very friendly thing to ask of the users of my app.

Comment: To be clear, I have Drive installed on my iPhone.  For some reason it does not show up in the FilePicker though.

Comment: Do you want to use any other app on your phone and get the content inside?

Comment: I'll try to answer the question although I am not quite certain how to interpret it.  I think you are asking why I would need to store the internal data from my application outside the app.  1) To back up the data.  2) To share the data with other people. 3) To transfer the data between one's own personal devices.  Does that answer your question?